# How to debug a variable accessed through a macro in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

For example, If I have a variable

```
int main()
{
   MyNamespace::MyObject.MyVariable++;  
}
```

I can easily place the mouse over the variable and see it's current value. However, If I use a macro,

```
#define MyMacro MyNamespace::MyObject

int main()
{
   MyMacro.MyVariable++;  
}
```

If I place the mouse over the variable, I can't see it anymore. `Step into` obviosuly doesn't help since I'm not calling a function so there's nothing to step into.

And even If right click `MyVariable`, and use the option `Add Watch`, it will add `MyMacro.MyVariable` into the `watch list` which obviously doesn't exist, rather than `MyNamespace::MyObject.MyVariable`), so I have to do it manually, which is quite annoying.

Comment: Don't use macros when you don't really need them. Ask Microsoft why they did't expect what you did

Comment: The short answer is that a macro is almost certainly the wrong way to go.  Is there a reason you haven't put in your question that explains why you want to do this?

Comment: The old style approach - the only real approach - is to use `/P` command line parameter to generate the post-preprocessed source code, then inspect the result.  And then edit and repeat.  You can get to that in the IDE in the VC++ project property page (C/C++/Preprocessor tab).  (Oh wait, I thought you were debugging a macro, like your title said.  You're actually debugging something _hidden_ behind a macro.  So, you are on your own to do it yourself.)